# (x*2) > y SQL display statement

Tags: sql

i'm struggling to get my function to display the items that are more than double the 'retail' price. My current code is;

```
   SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY_NAME, S.STORE_ADDRESS,
    I.ITEM_ID, I.ITEM_NAME, I.COST, I.RETAIL, I.MAKER
    FROM COMPANY C, INVENTORY I, STORE S
    WHERE(
    I.COST > I.RETAIL * 2
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID
);
```

My variables are all numbers. I'm getting the missing right paranthesis error on the line with I.COST > I.RETAIL * 2.

Comment: `WHERE(` should be `WHERE`, but you also need to remove the group by.

Comment: @Zohar true, but also need to join the tables.

Comment: @ShadowWizard correct, I can't believe I've missed that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have aggregation function so you don't need group by

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY_NAME, S.STORE_ADDRESS,
I.ITEM_ID, I.ITEM_NAME, I.COST, I.RETAIL, I.MAKER
FROM COMPANY C, INVENTORY I, STORE S
WHERE  I.COST > (I.RETAIL * 2);
```

*be careful that you  have not relation condition between the tables*

Comment: Sorry couldn't do it before as it still had the timer on it

Answer (score 1):

Your distinct implies you are already grouping by the objects involved ..try this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY_NAME, S.STORE_ADDRESS,
    I.ITEM_ID, I.ITEM_NAME, I.COST, I.RETAIL, I.MAKER
    FROM COMPANY C, INVENTORY I, STORE S
    WHERE
    I.COST > I.RETAIL * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the I.RETAIL * 2 in brackets.
i.e (I.RETAIL * 2)
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables and there has to be a cross reference table in there somewhere. Something like:

```
SELECT C.COMPANY_NAME, S.STORE_ADDRESS,
I.ITEM_ID, I.ITEM_NAME, I.COST, I.RETAIL, I.MAKER
FROM COMPANY C
JOIN INVENTORY I
ON C.CompanyID = I.MAKERID
JOIN xrefStoreInventory SI
ON SI.ItemID = I.ItemID
JOIN STORE S
ON S.StoreID = SI.StoreID
WHERE  I.COST > (I.RETAIL * 2);
```